# Does not update translations in rosetta for Django

Tags: django, translation, django-i18n, django-rosetta

I have some translations in rosetta and it have worked. Now I need to update some of those trasnlations. I have done it in rosetta adminstrator and checked it in .po file, and are ok.

Now, I compile the .po file, `django-admin.py compilemessages -l en`, and the file compiles, later I restart the server. The problem is that the changes are not showed.

What is wrong? Is some command missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was my bad, rosetta worked perfect, there was translations through CMS (mezzanine). Sorry,

Answer (score 0):

Check "fuzzy" flag and file permissions.

Comment: I have cheked it. was my bad, rosetta worked perfect, there was translations through CMS (mezzanine). Sorry,